# How to translate this Android Kotlin code to Java code

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

```
class MainAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var list: List<Int> = arrayListOf()
    var tracker: SelectionTracker<Long>? = null

    init {
        setHasStableIds(true)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val number = list[position]
        tracker?.let {
            holder.bind(number, it.isSelected(position.toLong()))
        }
    }
```

I would like to understand this example. What does `tracker?.let` translate to? And also what's the equivalent of `init` in Java?

Comment: Do you want to convert this code into java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend another way to read kotlin code assuming you are well familiar with java. You can use below option in android studio.

[image: Decode kt file]

After this just click decompile and Voila!, you will get java code.

[image: byte code]

So now you can read any kotlin code.

Answer (score 0):

```
init
```

As per documentation - init is equivalent to a constructor in java. here we can initialize a variable.

```
let
```

As per documentation- Kotlin **let** is a scoping function wherein the variables declared inside the expression cannot be used outside.

```
tracker?.let {
    holder.bind(number, it.isSelected(position.toLong()))
}
```

here **it** is a copy of tracker.changing **it** will not affect on tracker variable.

Answer (score 0):

MainAdapter equivalent in Java code is something like that:

```
class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    SelectionTracker<Long> tracker;

    public MainAdapter() {
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int number = list.get(position);

        if (tracker != null) {
            holder.bind(number, tracker.isSelected(position.toLong()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class M {
    var age: Int = 0
}
```

```
fun main(){
    val m = M()
    m.let {
        it.age = 11
     }
    println(m.age)
}
```

above output "11", so "let" doesn't copy the receiver, "it" is just point to the receiver, it has side-effect